# Is there a way to add times that total greater than 24 hrs?

Tags: openoffice, openoffice-calc

I'm trying to add a sum of cells with the format HH:MM. If the sum exceeds 24h I get strange results like 3:55h

I tried [H]:MM:S

Which format should I choose?
I'm using open-office calc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For OpenOffice you should try [HH]:MM:SS

That will allow the number of hours beyond 24 to show (e.g. 12:00:00 + 13:00:00 = 25:00:00)

Answer (score 1):

For Excel you can use the format, **[h]:mm:ss**

Comment: Thanks, I tried this, and edited my question unforunatly this didn't work with open-office. I'm sorry if the OP was confusing.